# Zf2 form text element watermark hit

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

```
 $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'size',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Size',
            ),
        ));
```

How do i get a watermark hint for this form element ?

Comment: what is a "watermark hint" ?

Answer (score 0):

If *watermark hint* means for you HTML5 placeholder, do like this:

```
      $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
        'name' => 'name',
        'attributes'    => array(
            'placeholder' => 'Name'
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Name',
            'description' => 'Type a name [optional]'
        )
    ));
```